# How do you parse JSON in Swift when you continue to get an EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error?

Tags: swift

I am trying to access GitHub statistics, and the information from the API is being returned as

```
[ 
{"name" : "Peter"},
{ "name" : "Daniel"},
]
```

Everytime I attempt to parse this, I get an EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error.
Is there an easy way to parse this using Swift?

Comment: I was using a JSON parsing method to parse some of their previous API calls, but when I attempted to parse the above code, I received a parsing error. If I could get this information into an array, I think it would be smooth sailing. I have never seen this syntax before, however.

Comment: Well, your issue is that `=` should be `:` in JSON. Just replace `=` by `:` and use JSON parsing: http://www.topcoder.com/blog/calling-apis-parsing-json-with-swift/

Comment: That is my question. [ ] is not JSON, correct?

Comment: @DosCadenas `[ ]` declares a JSON array. The problem isn't that your data is an array, it's that JSON doesn't allow trailing commas. Remove the last comma and it will be valid JSON.

Comment: This are all syntax errors in my question. I am not writing any of this code, I am using the GitHub api. My parser won't work any longer for some reason when there are brackets.

Comment: @DosCadenas Can you give us the Swift code you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying a more traditional approach when parsing, I attempted to use:

```
//Set up the network request, asynchronously
    let urlPath: String = "https://api.github.com/users/" + userName
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

    //Make the asynchronous request
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        var err: NSError


        //Store the JSON data from the Github api
        var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

This gave me an EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error

So, I tried another parsing method

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let queue: NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()


    //Store the JSON data from the Github api
    var jsonResult: NSData  = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)

    var error:NSError?

    // Retrieve Data
    var JSONData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url, options: NSDataReadingOptions(), error: &error)
    // Create another error optional
    var jsonerror:NSError?
    // We don't know the type of object we'll receive back so use AnyObject
    let swiftObject:AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&jsonerror)!
    // JSONObjectWithData returns AnyObject so the first thing to do is to downcast this to a known type
    if let nsDictionaryObject = swiftObject as? NSDictionary {
        if let swiftDictionary = nsDictionaryObject as Dictionary? {
            println(swiftDictionary)
        }
    }
    else if let nsArrayObject = swiftObject as? NSArray {
        if let swiftArray = nsArrayObject as Array? {
            println(swiftArray)
        }
    }
```

This method allowed me to parse the information